# reactjs template looping ternary operators and markup

Tags: json, reactjs

I am new to reactjs, I've json which has some nested arrays and need to replicate the static markup with conditionals as I loop though the json.

//current code

```
                    {
                      list.title
                        ? list.list.map(function (li, k) {
                          return (
                            <div key={k} className='row grid__row--offset--15'>
                              <div className='small-9 medium-7 large-6 columns border--solid--right-blue'>
                                <p className='text--font-size-14 text--right'>{index + 1}.{j + 1}.{k + 1}</p>
                              </div>
                              <div className='small-51 medium-52 large-53 columns medium-offset-1'>
                                <p className='text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified'>{li}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          )
                        })
                        : null
                    }
```

//need something like this where I can add a gap div above and below the looped segment.

```
<div className='row grid__row--offset--20' />
```

-- but this creates a syntax error

```
                    {
                      list.title
                        ? <div className='row grid__row--offset--20' />
                        list.list.map(function (li, k) {
                          return (
                            <div key={k} className='row grid__row--offset--15'>
                              <div className='small-9 medium-7 large-6 columns border--solid--right-blue'>
                                <p className='text--font-size-14 text--right'>{index + 1}.{j + 1}.{k + 1}</p>
                              </div>
                              <div className='small-51 medium-52 large-53 columns medium-offset-1'>
                                <p className='text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified'>{li}</p>
                              </div>
                            </div>
                          )
                        })
                        <div className='row grid__row--offset--20' />
                        : null
                    }
```

Comment: you want to write exactly 2nd way ?

Comment: Something like that yes -- above and below the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
{list.title && <div className='row grid__row--offset--20' />}
     {
              list.title &&
                list.list.map(function (li, k) {
                  return (
                    <div key={k} className='row grid__row--offset--15'>
                      <div className='small-9 medium-7 large-6 columns border--solid--right-blue'>
                        <p className='text--font-size-14 text--right'>{index + 1}.{j + 1}.{k + 1}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div className='small-51 medium-52 large-53 columns medium-offset-1'>
                        <p className='text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified'>{li}</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  )
                })


            }
{list.title && <div className='row grid__row--offset--20' /> }
```

Answer (score 0):

You get a syntax error because in return you need to have the map function within `{}` and return a single element from the ternary operation

```
{
                  list.title
                    ? <div><div className='row grid__row--offset--20' />
                    { list.list && list.list.map(function (li, k) {
                      return (
                        <div key={k} className='row grid__row--offset--15'>
                          <div className='small-9 medium-7 large-6 columns border--solid--right-blue'>
                            <p className='text--font-size-14 text--right'>{index + 1}.{j + 1}.{k + 1}</p>
                          </div>
                          <div className='small-51 medium-52 large-53 columns medium-offset-1'>
                            <p className='text--font-size-14 paragraph--justified'>{li}</p>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      )
                    })
                    <div className='row grid__row--offset--20' /></div>
                    }
                    : null 
}
```